# Ajax-based Django MultipleChoiceField

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms

Does anyone know of an alternative implementation of Django's MultipleChoiceField that instead of rendering as a `<select>`, renders as an `<input type="text">` which loads options via an Ajax search (preferrably using jquery), and stores selected options in a hidden field?

I have an application where the user needs to select multiple "people" in a MultipleChoiceField, but the available people can number in the thousands, so it's impractical to list them all.

Answer (score 1):

Yup here it is [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects). Or [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) is also a good library to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        choices=SOMECHOICE,
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
        help_text='',
        label='',
        required=True,
        error_messages={'required': "This field is required (by default the value should be 'DEFAULT')."},
    )
```